# Sending pdf as attachment causes undefined error in Chrome browser

Tags: django, http, pdf, google-chrome

Using Django, I am sending a pdf file from the server. If I send it as an attachment using:

```
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=test.pdf'
```

it downloads fine, but in the Chrome console there is an error:

```
GET http://12.345.678.09/vpas/?print_confirm=true undefined (undefined)
```

If I send the pdf without setting the Content-Disposition of the response, there is no error. What is the cause of this error and how can I get rid of it?

This is the http (from Firefox - couldn't get as many details from Chrome):

```
http://12.345.678.09/vpas/?print_confirm=true&vpa_id_to_print=2355

GET /vpas/?print_confirm=true&vpa_id_to_print=2355 HTTP/1.1
Host: 12.345.678.09
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.17) Gecko/20110420 Firefox/3.6.17 GTB7.1 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: sessionid=fdabaccd2a731fd459cd5d6c3f5004f1
Cache-Control: max-age=0

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/0.5.33
Date: Mon, 02 May 2011 00:59:48 GMT
Content-Type: application/pdf
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Cookie
Content-Disposition: attachment;
Set-Cookie: sessionid=fdabaccd2a731fd459cd5d6c3f5004f1; expires=Mon, 02-May-2011 01:59:48 GMT; Max-Age=3600; Path=/
```

This is the http I could get from Chrome:

```
Request URL:http://12.345.678.09/vpas/?print_confirm=true&vpa_id_to_print=2355
Request Headers
Accept:application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/534.24 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/11.0.696.60 Safari/534.24
Query String Parameters
print_confirm:true
vpa_id_to_print:2355
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add an HTTP trace, or at least a printout of the header fields as received by the browser.

Comment: Added above. I don't know how to get a more detailed trace from Chrome.

Comment: The trace doesn't show the filename parameter in Content-Disposition...

Answer (score 15):

The issue is caused by Chrome 16 following the correct RFC standard.

You have to surround the file name with double quotes. See http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=103618

In your case, it would be ...

```
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="test.pdf"'
```

Also important, which you've done already, using semi-colons to separate the values rather than commas. This could cause the same outcome in Chrome

Comment: Impresive, you have save me at least 2 research bug hours.

Comment: As this is the correct answer (worked for me too), I'd suggest @mitch to mark this answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered this error today in rendering dynamic pdfs, after a recent Chrome upgrade.  Previously the code had worked fine in all browsers.

My work-around was to **remove any embedded spaces and commas** in the filename.  There may be other meta characters to remove, but this fixed the problem for my users.

For the benefit of the search engines, the error appearing in Chrome:

**Duplicate headers received from server**

```
Error 349 (net::ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_MULTIPLE_CONTENT_DISPOSITION)
```

*The response from the server contained duplicate headers. This problem is  generally the result of a misconfigured website or proxy. Only the website  or proxy administrator can fix this issue.*

Answer (score 0):

```
if not 'HTTP_USER_AGENT' in request.META or u'WebKit' in request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT']:
    # Safari 3.0 and Chrome 2.0 accepts UTF-8 encoded string directly.
    filename_header = 'filename=%s' % original_filename.encode('utf-8')
elif u'MSIE' in request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT']:
    try:
        original_filename.encode('ascii')
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        original_filename = 'subtitles.' + h.file_type

    filename_header = 'filename=%s' % original_filename
else:
    # For others like Firefox, we follow RFC2231 (encoding extension in HTTP headers).
    filename_header = 'filename*=UTF-8\'\'%s' % iri_to_uri(original_filename.encode('utf-8'))

response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; ' + filename_header
```

This is example for file downloading. It is so complex because different browsers handle "not ascii" names in different ways and this is working for Chrome.

Comment: Chrome does handle RFC 2231, so does IE9. The only one left not supporting it is Safari.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried 1) `filename = 'print_confirm.pdf'.encode('utf-8')` and `response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % filename` and 2) `response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename*=UTF-8\'\'%s' % iri_to_uri('print_confirm.pdf'.encode('utf-8'))` I still get undefined in the Chrome 11 console.

Comment: Maybe the problem is something else. What happens if you do not send the header field at all?

Comment: With Chrome 12.0.742.91 beta-m, instead of the previous error, I now get the warning "Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/pdf."

Answer (score 0):

```
ctrl+shift+j
```

opens up the chrome console.

network will have the header info.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the 'transfer-encoding: chunked' HTTP header in your response is causing the issue. I had a similar issue on an ASP .NET web application. The Chrome issue is documented here:
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=83332

Try setting a content-length header with the size of the PDF file attachment in bytes. I don't know anything about Django, so you might also need to look into a way to explicitly suppress the transfer-encoding: chunked header as well.

I also noticed that prematurely closing the HTTP response (again, this was ASP .NET) had an adverse impact on Chrome being able to open the PDF file.